# bcrypt.gentSalt is not a function is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, hash

I am stuck while hashing my password. Here is my code :

```
const salt = await bcrypt.gentSalt(10);
const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
```

This is my user body data code:

```
const user = new User({
  name: req.body.name,
  email: req.body.email,
  password: hashPassword,
});
```

Comment: `"gentSalt" !== "genSalt"`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt Check the example under "Usage":

```
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
  bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
    // Store hash in your password DB.
  });
});
```

It's telling you it doesn't exist because you have a typo. You should be using `.genSalt()` instead of `.gentSalt()`.